# How to get dir of a directory tree iterator without the full pathname

Tags: php

I have the following code which outputs a full path name. I simply want the folder name and not the whole path.

I was thinking of using substr but I have no way of knowing how long the username is so that won't work.

Is there something similar that will get me just the folder name and not the full path?

My code:

```
$it = new RecursiveTreeIterator(new 
RecursiveDirectoryIterator("C:\wamp642\www\\refit\code\username_1", 
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS)); 
foreach($it as $path => $branch)
{
    if(is_dir($path))
    {
        echo $path;
        if(!file_exists("files"))
        {
            mkdir("files");
         }

    }
    if(is_file($path))
    {
         echo ' $path;
    }

}
```

Comment: `echo ' $path;` ??? Is that a typo or a real error in your code

Comment: Look at the [`pathinfo` function in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: Thanks Riggs. Do you want credit? post this as your answer and I'll check it: `$brownie = pathinfo($path);
  echo $brownie['basename'];`

Comment: No. G o ahead and post that as your own answer. You can even accept it and get reps for it

Answer (score 0):

$brownie = pathinfo($path); 
echo $brownie['basename'];